# Checking permissions of a user with a site collection

Tags: sharepoint, permissions

I want to check whether a user has permissions to a site collection. But i dono how to use `SPSite.DoesUserHavePermissions()`.

What is `SPReusableAcl`? How can i get it for checking the permissions of the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't the MSDN article ([SPWeb.DoesUserHavePermissions Method (String, SPBasePermissions)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms441848.aspx)) help you? The example code can be used to check whether the user has access to a site collection:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://localhost"))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    // Make sure the current user can enumerate permissions.
                    if (web.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPBasePermissions.EnumeratePermissions))
                    {
                        // Specify the permission to check.
                        SPBasePermissions permissionToCheck = SPBasePermissions.ManageLists;
                        Console.WriteLine("The following users have {0} permission:", permissionToCheck);

                        // Check the permissions of users who are explicitly assigned permissions.
                        SPUserCollection users = web.Users;
                        foreach (SPUser user in users)
                        {
                            string login = user.LoginName;
                            if (web.DoesUserHavePermissions(login, permissionToCheck))
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(login);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

In the sample code above you would just have to change your Site URL and the Variable `permissionToCheck`. SPBasePermissions has a lot of possible permissions to check against, you can see the enumeration here ([SPBasePermissions Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbasepermissions.aspx)).

Actually there are a lot of tutorials on how to check some user's permissions and you are not limited to `DoesUserHavePermissions`, see the following [Google Search](http://www.google.com/search?q=sharepoint+check+user).

Comment: I guess your code just checks whether the user has permissions to the top level site, not to the site collection. Top level site != Site collection. Ain't I right?

Comment: Top level site == Site collection - but that's not important now ;-) If you want to check the permissions of a site collection/subsite not being the root, you just have to edit the URL (as I mentioned) `new SPSite("http://localhost")` this URL could also be `"http://mysharepointweb/sites/mySiteCollection"`

Answer (score 0):

As usual, the MSDN examples provide nice textbook examples that do not always apply to real-life scenarios.

In the context of an application page running on SharePoint 2010, from what i understand this code needs to be wrapped in a call to RunWithElevatedPrivileges and even then, as my comment implies, it seems there is an implied catch-22 in the requirements. This works for me (the LoginName is just the FBA username or "domain\user" for AD user for the site - in our case an e-mail address is used):

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    using (SPSite elevatedSite = new SPSite(siteCollectionUrl))
    {
        foreach (SPSite siteCollection in elevatedSite.WebApplication.Sites)
        {
            using (SPWeb elevatedWeb = siteCollection.OpenWeb())
            {
                bool allowUnsafeUpdates = elevatedWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates;
                bool originalCatchValue = SPSecurity.CatchAccessDeniedException;
                SPSecurity.CatchAccessDeniedException = false;

                try
                {
                    elevatedWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                    // You can't verify permissions if the user does not exist and you
                    // can't ensure the user if the user does not have access so we
                    // are stuck with a try-catch
                    SPUser innerUser = elevatedWeb.EnsureUser(loginName);

                    if (null != innerUser)
                    {
                        string splogin = innerUser.LoginName;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(splogin) && elevatedWeb.DoesUserHavePermissions(splogin, SPBasePermissions.ViewPages))
                        {
                            // this user has permissions; any other login - particularly one that
                            // results in an UnauthorizedAccessException - does not
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
                {
                    // handle exception
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    // do nothing
                }
                finally
                {
                    elevatedWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = allowUnsafeUpdates;
                    // reset the flag
                    SPSecurity.CatchAccessDeniedException = originalCatchValue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

SPSite.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPReusableAcl, SPBasePermissions);

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on what SPReusableAcl is?

Comment: ReusableAcl: "Use the ReusableAcl property of the SPWeb, SPList, or SPListItem class to return the ACL for a Web site, list, or list item. For any class that implements the ISecurableObject interface, you can use the ReusableAcl property to return the ACL. To return the ACL for a site collection, use either the GetReusableAclForScope or GetAllReusableAcls method of the SPSite class."